The .sink block inside the ViewModel class is called automatically when launching the controller a second time
I have a SwiftUI view embedded inside Controller A using UIHostingController. Controller A is launched from Controller B. The SwiftUI view uses a ViewModel class. In the ViewModel, I have subscribed to some publishers and I want to send data to Controller A.
//This is the ViewModel file that contains a publisher to receive the video URL upon capture, and I am sending this URL to a controller using PassthroughSubject.

class GenericCameraViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let xCamSession: XCamSession
    
    var preview: some View {
        xCamSession.interactivePreview()
    }
    
    private var subscription = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    public var cameraEventSubject = PassthroughSubject<GenericCameraResult, Never>()
    
    
    init(genericCameraConfiguration: GenericCameraConfiguation) {

        // Prepare video album cover
        xCamSession.videoFilePublisher
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .map {result -> URL? in
                if case .success(let file) = result {
                    return file.path
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            }
            .sink(receiveValue: { fileURL in
                debugPrint("Receive file url")
                self.cameraEventSubject.send(GenericCameraResult(event: .capturedVideo, images: nil, videoFile: fileURL))
//                if self.shouldSendData {
//                    self.xCamSession.terminateSession({ result in
//                        self.cameraEventSubject.send(GenericCameraResult(event: .capturedVideo, images: nil, videoFile: fileURL))
//                        debugPrint("Receive file url")
//                        
//                    })
//                }
                
            })
            .store(in: &subscription)
        
        }
}

// a function in the controller to add SwiftUI view and subscribe the subject
    
    // display the measure view as a view controller child
    private func addAsAChild(){
        
        //let config = GenericCameraConfiguation(captureMode: .photo,canCaputreMultiplePhotos: true, cameraPosition: .back,cameraPhotoFlash: .off,cameraVideoTorch: .auto)
        
        let viewModel = GenericCameraViewViewModel(genericCameraConfiguration: configuration)
        let videoContentView = GenericCameraView(viewModel: viewModel)
        viewModel.cameraEventSubject
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) // Ensure sink runs on main thread
        .sink(
            receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print("-- completion", completion)
                self.cancellables.first?.cancel()
                self.dismiss(animated: true)
                
            },
            receiveValue: {[weak self] result in
                viewModel.shouldSendData = false
                switch(result.event){
                case .closePressed:
                    viewModel.cameraEventSubject.send(completion: .finished)
                    debugPrint("Close Button Pressed")
                    break
                case .donePressed:
                    debugPrint("Done Button Pressed  \(result.images ?? [])")
                    viewModel.cameraEventSubject.send(completion: .finished)
                    let capturedImages = result.images ?? []
                    let arrImagePaths = self?.saveImages(images: capturedImages)
                    self?.mDelegate?.capturedImagesPath(capturedImages: arrImagePaths ?? [])
                    break;
                case .capturedPhoto:
                    debugPrint("capturedPhoto Button Pressed  \(result.images ?? [])")
                    let capturedImages = result.images ?? []
                    let arrImagePaths = self?.saveImages(images: capturedImages)
                    self?.mDelegate?.capturedImagesPath(capturedImages: arrImagePaths ?? [])
                    
                case .capturedVideo:
                    debugPrint("capturedVideo Button Pressed  \(result.videoFile ??  URL.init(string: "https://cameraxaapp.com")!)")
                    self?.mDelegate?.capturedVideoUrl(videoUrl: result.videoFile)
                    //viewModel.cameraEventSubject.send(completion: .finished)
                }
            }
        ).store(in: &cancellables)
        
        let hostingViewController = HostingController(rootView: videoContentView)
        addChildWithView(hostingViewController)
    }

To achieve this, I added a PassthroughSubject inside the ViewModel and subscribed to this subject inside Controller A. I am sending data using this subject within the publisher's .sink method, and it works fine. However, when I open Controller A again, the .sink method of the publisher is called automatically.

SwiftUI doesn't work with view model objects because the View structs are a view model already. It would be best for you to supply closures to VideoContentView for your callback events, e.g.
videoContentView.donePressed = { 
    xCamSession.finished()
}

struct VideoContentView: View {
    var donePressed: (() -> Void)?
...

FYI, when trying to use Combine without using one of its main operators like combineLatest, zip or merge and just dumping the pipeline down the sink it generally means your use case doesn't need Combine at all.
